# unable to fix mysql_num_rows error message

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to count num_rows using the mysql_num_rows function, I keep getting an error. my query has no error. what could be the problem

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$search = $_POST['search'];
// connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "ajax") or die ("could not connect to    database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM searchengine  WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' ";
$get_query = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("can't execute query");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query);

$num = mysql_num_rows($get_query);
echo $num;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)){
echo "resuslts found ".'<br/>';
echo $row['title'];


}


}
else{
echo " not set";
}



?>
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: You wanna post the error?

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) hole there. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in

Comment: Isn't it $num = mysqli_num_rows($get_query) instead? And what happened if you count the rows before you fetch your array?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the mysqli (note the **i**) and mysql functions. The two libraries are **NOT** interchangeable, and a result from one is not usable in the other.

The code should be:

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($get_query);
            ^----
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `mysqli`

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($get_query);
```

Comment: I think you mean `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` in your example code ;)

Comment: @zdhickman: Yes indeed :D now please thumb back up :D

Answer (score 0):

Your $get_query is in mysqli syntax while on the other hand you are using  $num in mysql..
Try the same format for both. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$search = $_POST['search'];

// connect to database

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "ajax") or die ("could not connect to    database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM searchengine  WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' ";

$get_query = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("can't execute query");

$num = mysqli_num_rows($get_query);

echo $num . "resuslts found ".'<br/>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)){

echo $row['title'];

}

}

else{

echo " not set";

}
```